# Error installing Passport for API auth via Composer package manager in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel-6, laravel-passport

I am trying API authentication in Laravel v6. When i try to install Passport `composer require laravel/passport` it says

```
Using version ^10.1 for laravel/passport
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.20.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.20.7
    - laravel/passport 10.x-dev requires illuminate/http ^8.2 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[8.x-dev, v8.10.0, v8.11.0, v8.11.1, v8.11.2, v8.12.0, v8.12.1, v8.12.2, v8.12.3, v8.13.0, v8.14.0, v8.15.0, v8.16.0, v8.16.1, v8.17.0, v8.17.2, v8.18.0, v8.18.1, v8.2.0, v8.3.0, v8.4.0, v8.5.0, v8.6.0, v8.7.0, v8.7.1, v8.8.0, v8.9.0].
    - laravel/passport v10.1.0 requires illuminate/http ^8.2 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[8.x-dev, v8.10.0, v8.11.0, v8.11.1, v8.11.2, v8.12.0, v8.12.1, v8.12.2, v8.12.3, v8.13.0, v8.14.0, v8.15.0, v8.16.0, v8.16.1, v8.17.0, v8.17.2, v8.18.0, v8.18.1, v8.2.0, v8.3.0, v8.4.0, v8.5.0, v8.6.0, v8.7.0, v8.7.1, v8.8.0, v8.9.0].
    - don't install illuminate/http 8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.20.7
    - don't install illuminate/http v8.10.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.20.7
    - don't install illuminate/http v8.11.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.20.7
    - don't install illuminate/http v8.9.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.20.7
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.20.7, required as ^6.20) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.20.7].
    - Installation request for laravel/passport ^10.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[10.x-dev, v10.1.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I've searched so many related questions but none of them are helpful for me